# The provided configuration is not supported on this device

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have Iphone 7, and am working on 3D face filters like tiktok but whenever i run on the app from xcode it shows error `The provided configuration is not supported on this device` and only shows black screen

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: @Frankenstein am using ARKit and RealityKit

Comment: What's the OS on your device?

Comment: Its 13.5 on the IPhone and MacOS am running latest version

Comment: You're using a real iphone 7 with ios 13.5 right? Not simulator?

Comment: yeah, am using real device

Answer (score 2):

You can't use all ARKit features on iPhone 7, some features require A12 processor, at least, and higher. For example: on iPhone 7 you can't use such features as People Occlusion, Body Tracking, simultaneous 3-Face Detection or Scene Reconstraction.

And remember: you have always to check with `if` or `guard` statement wheather a feature is supported on current device:

```
guard let config = arView.session.configuration as? ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
else { 
    print("You can't run this config on this device.") 
}

guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
else { 
    print("People Occlusion isn't supported here.") 
}

config.frameSemantics.insert(.personSegmentationWithDepth)

arView.session.run(config)
```